# tinymce 4 loading but showing tinymce.get is undefined

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, tinymce, ejs

I'm working in a form update section using Tinymce and jquery and using ejs for load form including textarea  and i call tinymce (tinymce init) using JavaScript function right after the ejs loaded.
The editor is working fine, but when i use

```
tinymce.get("content-text").setContent( $(".grid:first").html() );
```

for set content to editor its showing error.
if i load the textarea form and load tinymce again it will work ;) I don't what is happening here.

Comment: If you are using `tinymce.get` before your tinymce instance is strapped to your form's `textarea`, no wonder you are getting an error. Have you tried using your `.get` inside a `$(document).ready()`?

Comment: yes , i'm writing all in document.ready

Comment: Could you please post your entire code?

Comment: pls see the green marked lines 
https://docs.google.com/document/d/1lroVIRYX-nK0Oo4l-9anrEeekhqt9QIqnaBViakqoAA/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your comments, what I suggest is that you instantiate tinymce outside your `$(document).ready()`, and before your html form.

Comment: actually i don't understand, i'm initialising and calling the function in document.ready.
Same error getting when i place the loadtinymce function outside the ready

Comment: When you instantiate it outside your document.ready, do you do it before of after your html form?

Comment: Tinymce load function placed outside the ready, and calling the tinymce load functin after the ejs loads, when i load the form again it will work

Comment: Try calling the tinymce load function before ejs loads the form.

Comment: Could you please indicate your code sequence according to DOM?

Comment: in doument ready i calling form load, after loadung form ejs i will call loadtynymce function. its defined out side the document ready

Comment: The sequence should be 1/ initialize tinyMCE (outside `document.ready()`, preferably at header level or on top of your HTML), 2/ initialize your form (HTML or whatever) and 3/ use `get` functions in `document.ready()`.